# An example of Asynchronous Java Restlet webservice?

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, restlet

Is there any example of **Asynchronous Java Restlet webservice** is available?

I want to implement Asynchronous Java Restlet webservice with Apache Tomcat 6.

Comment: @david99world, I dont know is it possible in Restlet. I didnt find any tutorial on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous RESTFul services are only just defined for [JAX-RS 2.0](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/).

Restlet does not support JAX-RS at the moment.

[Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), which is the Reference Implementation of JAX-RS [does not support](http://jersey.java.net/jersey20.html) asynchronous services, too.

Comment: Thanks Tichodroma for your reply. So how can I achieve Asynchronous webservice.

Comment: Using JAX-RS/REST: you can't until JAX-RS 2.0 is released. If you don't want to use JAX-RS you can go for Servlets that support Asynchronous Operations since Servlet 3.0.

Comment: Thanks Tichodroma for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: Restlet does support JAX-RS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671845/how-to-set-up-a-restlet-server-with-jaxrs-and-jaxb